# paypal with pure angular/java script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, paypal

I use html code to allow user tp buy by paypal:

```
     <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                                <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="TM8DDJ5CWYG9E">
                                <table>
                                    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="{{lang.buy}}">
                                        {{lang.buy}}
                                    </td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
                                    <option value="item1 ">item1 </option>
                                    <option value="item2">item2 </option>
                                </select> </td></tr>
                                </table>
                                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="ILS">
                                <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/he_IL/IL/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal">
```

but how can I get response from paypal when user buy an item? there is a way to do it with pure java script/angular? (without server side)

thanks

Comment: I don't think the question you refered help me. I don't want just a page to return - I want to run code in case of successfull transaction. what if user that not buy will do to the buy url ?

Comment: and I don't want to use server side...